# Boot configuration error:  Fedora 15

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, grub

I have a Fedora 15 installation on VirtualBox. When I added another virtual hd it erased all the `grub.conf`.

Now I'm trying to manually add the CD-LIVE correct command in `grub.conf`, but is giving error:

[image]

GRUB.CONF:

[image: GRUB.CONF]

Command blkid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My `/boot/grub/grub.conf` is much more complicated than that.  Fedora 15:

```
default=0
timeout=0
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.41.4-1.fc15.i686)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.41.4-1.fc15.i686 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lenovotower-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.41.4-1.fc15.i686.img
title Fedora (2.6.41.1-1.fc15.i686)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.41.1-1.fc15.i686 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lenovotower-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.41.1-1.fc15.i686.img
title Fedora (2.6.40.6-0.fc15.i686)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.40.6-0.fc15.i686 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_lenovotower-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_lenovotower/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.40.6-0.fc15.i686.img
```

This includes the latest updates as of yesterday, Friday December 16.

Comment: He is still with the error. But thank you for your attention.:)